# Why did my function for reading excel using openyxl through a loop fail?

Tags: python, excel, file, automation

The following is my code to try to read data from excel sheets:

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def read_excel_cell(file_name, sheets_name, row_num, col_num):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = wb[sheets_name]
    cell_value = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num).value
    wb.close()
    return cell_value


file_path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\23Spring\Research\Modulus Sheet for Python.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'AMX3'


# Create 2D array
OneD_array = []
for i in range(15):
    OneD_array.append(None)

A_radii = OneD_array
M_radii = OneD_array
X_radii = OneD_array
C_11 = OneD_array
C_12 = OneD_array
C_44 = OneD_array


# Value giving
for i in range(15):
    print(i)
    C_44[i] = read_excel_cell(file_path, sheet_name, 9, i + 2)
    C_11[i] = read_excel_cell(file_path, sheet_name, 7, i + 2)

print(C_11)
print(C_44)
```

However, it turns that the row_num of read_excel_cell() for C_44[i] depends on the value of row_num of read_excel_cell for C_11[i], and C_44[i] will always be identical to C_11[i] in the loop:

```
[52.0279273240934, 51.9836838712884, 51.2783587849919, 50.6318887803575, 49.3918150648935, 44.6609715933503, 44.6121948392434, 43.9507860783241, 43.401896009658, 42.513850149358, 36.4063958544744, 35.9985326487102, 35.5788745536048, 35.2588804567531, 34.6651641603469]
[52.0279273240934, 51.9836838712884, 51.2783587849919, 50.6318887803575, 49.3918150648935, 44.6609715933503, 44.6121948392434, 43.9507860783241, 43.401896009658, 42.513850149358, 36.4063958544744, 35.9985326487102, 35.5788745536048, 35.2588804567531, 34.6651641603469]
```

In this case, they are both from the 7th row of the sheet. However, the function works properly when used outside of a loop (but I don't understand why)

Comment: It's because all of your variables point to the same object. If you update any of `A_radii`, `M_radii`, `X_radii`, `C_11`, `C_12`, or `C_44`, the rest of the variables will get updated because you set them all equal to `OneD_array`. Instead, write a function that creates a the `OneD array`, and call the function to initialize each of the variables to a different object

Comment: Notwithstanding the issue highlighted by @NaumRaskind have you thought about performance of this? It may not matter but you're opening and closing the spreadsheet every time you want to read one cell!

Comment: So, the variables are changed whenever I change the value of any one of them? I thought that they only change through directly assigning values to them?